# Responsive image with the same height as another column in the same row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, grid-layout

I am trying to place an image to the right of a form and I need the image to be the same height as the form div. I'm having a really difficult time accomplishing this without distorting the image.

The image I'm using is 1920 X 1200.

The code that I have got is as follows:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 govx-form">
            <div class="form-background">
                <?php echo do_shortcode(); ?>
                <?php echo do_shortcode(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 govx-form price-results"    id="ap_pricing_results">
            <img src="wp-content/images/fourHeroesLarger_edit.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have of course tried to use css that makes the height match the height of the form but as soon as I do that it ruins the responsiveness of the image. Additionally, when I set a height I set the width to 100% to fill the div, but that distorts the image really bad.

I have also tried doing a background image with the following css styles:

```
.price-results {
    background-image: url(/wp-content/images/fourHeros.jpeg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 335px;
    background-position: top;
    height: 130px;
}
```

This works on smaller screen sizes but again ruins the picture on larger screen sizes.

Comment: Try using it as a background-image, like you did, but using `background-size: cover;`

Comment: That doesn't work either. It doesn't distort the image but it crops it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
.price-results {
background-image: url(/wp-content/images/fourHeros.jpeg) no-repeat;
background-size: 335px auto;
background-position: top;
}
```

Also, do you have a running website? It can help out in figuring it out.